# How to keep a backend running?

Tags: linux, spring, bash, backend

This is my first time deploying a backend and I can't seem to find this specific information, and I want to confirm if it is as simple as I think

1. ssh into server
2. run my backend on an independent sub-thread (so `java -jar backend.jar` but in another thread)
3. close ssh connection

Is it this simple?

Comment: The clean (and canonical) way would be to create (depending on the distro you use) a systemd-unit file or an init-script and start the process that way; that could/would also e.g. restart it when the server gets rebooted.  Here a random example https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-run-java-jar-application-with-systemd-on-linux/

Comment: You might want to launch the ssh connection in the background, not only the remote command. Therefore don't close it, just add a & and ensure you do not need an interactive shell and/or to enter password.

Comment: `ssh user@machine "nohup java -jar backend.jar &"` might do the trick.  This starts your JAR in an independent process, detached from the ssh one.  So ssh can exit and the backend will keep running.  But the "real" way to do this is what @tink has commented above.